# How do I implement binary search for an array of integers?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to implement binary search for an array of integers. I made sure that array sorted incrementally. But my function is not tracking all the cases and some of the checks fail. What am I missing here? 
`Value` stands for integer I'm trying to find.

```
bool search(int value, int array[], int n)
{   
    int left = 0;
    int right = n - 1;
    int middle = (left + right) / 2;

while (right >= left)
{
    if (array[middle] == value)
    return true;
    else if (array[middle] < value)
    right = middle;
    else if (array[middle] > value)
    left = middle + 1;

    middle = (left + right) / 2;
}

return false;
}
```

My guess is that some left or right border cases are not predicted. I also not strong about `while` condition.

Comment: You really should learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Debugger of use **printf** - debugging. Output of *left*, *middle*, *right* for a failing example should lead to the problem.

Comment: How do you implement binary search?  Carefully.  It's been observed that the first implementation of binary search was published in 1946, but the first *correct* implementation of binary search was published in 1960.  You'll learn a lot by debugging your own version, and making sure it works on all cases.

Comment: @MrSmith42 That's good idea, I'll try this out.

Comment: @SteveSummit Good point. I believe the typical pitfall is integer overflow in the `middle` computation, which is easily missed in human-scaled test cases. [Wikipedia has notes on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Implementation_issues). The recommended expression is `middle = left + (right - left) / 2;`.

Comment: See the Google blog [Extra, extra — read all about it](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) for a discussion of overflows in binary search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mixed left and right, if `array[middle] < value` you have to change `left`.

```
bool search(int value, int array[], int n)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = n - 1;
    int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;

    while (right >= left)
    {
        if (array[middle] == value)
            return true;
        else if (array[middle] > value)
            right = middle - 1;
        else if (array[middle] < value)
            left = middle + 1;

        middle = (left + right) / 2;
    }
    return false;
}
```

will work: http://ideone.com/VSAhnZ

Further improvements can be:

1. You can exclude `middle` in the `else` parts, because you have already proved that it is not the correct value (`right = middle;` => `right = middle - 1;`)
2. The second `else if` can be replaced by an `else`. If it is not the value and not smaller you do not have to test if it is larger.

Comment: Got it. Your answer helped me a lot, big thanks. Can't believe I couldn't figure out this kind of mixing for such a long time. I'll try to be more attentive in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Standard binary search algorithm can be found anywhere. but just correcting your code:

```
bool search(int value, int array[], int n)
{   
    int left = 0;
    int right = n - 1;
    int middle;
    while (left <= right)
    {
         middle = (left + right) / 2;    
        if (value > array[middle] )
            left = middle + 1;
        else if (value < array[middle])
            right = middle - 1;                
        else 
            return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```